# Spring boot set log level for all tests at once (without changing every test)

Tags: spring-boot, testing, logging

Is there a way to set the logging level only for tests at once? (Without copying the complete application.yml to test/resources)

Using a specific profile would mean to add this manually to all tests. Using `TestPropertySource` would also mean to change all tests.

Is there something that i can put into test/resources that just sets logging and take all other properties from default/active profile?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using logback, you can put `logback-test.xml` in `src/test/resources` and define all the relevant configurations there

So if you have a regular logback.xml in `src/main/resources` of the module, the `logback-test.xml` will override the definitions from the "regular" file

Example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <include resource="org/springframework/boot/logging/logback/base.xml" />
    <logger name="org.springframework" level="ERROR"/>
    <logger name="com.myapp" level="INFO"/>
 </configuration>
```

Comment: is there a way to set "all" or "*" to error? But only "com.myapp" to different leven?

Comment: Sure. You should set root logger level to ERROR. And a particular logger of interest (com.myapp) to different level. See https://logback.qos.ch/manual/configuration.html for root logger configuration example